# How to show multiple image in a google glass timeline

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

I have a table and want set multiple image in columns like

```
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td><img src="img1"/></td>
      <td>image 1 Name</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><img src="img2"/></td>
      <td>image 2 Name</td>
     </tr>
    <table>
```

/****************************************/
I want to add image dynamically, what I did.

```
   String cardHtml = "<article><section><table class=\"align-justify\"><thead>"
                + "<tr><td><h1>Image</h1></td><td><h1>Name</h1></td>"
                + "<tr></tr></thead><tbody><tr>";
        if (imgList != null) {
            for (String img : imgList) {
                imgUrl = appBaseUrl + "static/images/"
                        + img.getImgName();


                cardHtml += "<td><img src=\"" + imgUrl + "\"/>"
                        + img.getImgName() + "</td>";


            }
        }
        cardHtml += "</tr></tbody></table></section></article>";
```

I got image icon, but not image in the timeline card. But Image Name is showing properly, How can i solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<article>
  <section>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img src="https://mirror-api-playground.appspot.com/links/movie.jpg" height="80px" width="80px">            
          </td>
          <td>
           image 1 Name
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img src="https://mirror-api-playground.appspot.com/links/movie.jpg" height="80px" width="80px">            
          </td>
          <td>
            image 2 Name
          </td>
        </tr>        
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>
</article>
```

Output:
[image]

I strongly recommend you to use google's [playground](https://developers.google.com/glass/tools-downloads/playground) site. Edit those templates and have fun:)

Comment: Basically I did it, first i did in playground then I write the code. I add my code in the question, would you please check it

Comment: Yes I get the image in playground, when local server is running.

Comment: Teorically, to see images at localhost(server on your pc) from your Glass, you have to make a connection with the static ip of your pc(localhost is pointless for glass). try to get the ip address of your pc. then change localhost to your ip address. that should work if both glass and your pc are in the same network.

Comment: I replaced "localhost" to my "IP". playground can show both. but glass still cannot show image only the image icon.

Comment: I also set static URL, but same result.